# UIAlertController - showing blank titles in the alert

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, uialertcontroller

One of our app had alerts and we used to use the UIAlertView. We have updated from UIAlertView to UIAlertController (available from iOS8) since UIAlertView was deprecated in iOS9. Recently we received an issue from one of our customers saying that the alert buttons are showing blank sometimes but the buttons are functioning as expected in any case whether the title shows or not.

Device: iPad mini (1st generation)
OS version: iOS9

So, what could be the issue of showing blank sometimes for Alert buttons?

Comment: Show your code that sets the titles of the actions.

Comment: Change tintColor. Your App must have a white tintColor, than these UIAlertController catch.

Comment: Show the alert view controller button action code

Comment: @OnikIV Sorry, I didn't get you! By default, the button titles are in blue color. We were unable to reproduce this, but our customer shared our app screenshot with the blank button titles. He mentioned that the blank issue is not every time. Sometimes, they show the titles but not everytime.

Comment: @SrinivasG I had behaviors like this, than AlertController changes tintColor, or some, after presenting modally a PickerViewController, (UIImagePicker..., CNContactPicker..., DocumentPicker... or so on). If you have severals storyBoards, I don't know but sound like in some place you are changing the App tinColor. Looks in all your code "tintColor property to check and also in Story and Xibs. Good luck.

Comment: We haven't used the app tint color explicitly. I believe, by default the app tint color will be white

Answer (score 1):

I tried sample one.It works perfectly

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Show Actions" message:@"Action Title" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction *save = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"SAVE" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
[alertController addAction:save];

UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"CANCEL" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
[alertController addAction:cancel];

UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
[alertController addAction:ok];

[alertController addAction:ok];
[alertController addAction:save];
[alertController addAction:cancel];

[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Output result is

[image]

Comment: The customer reported that the button titles are showing some times but not every time. Sometimes, they are blank

Comment: Did you try with my answer?

Comment: I have already using the similar code but the text differs ;) BTW, the issue is not reproduced everytime. So, it is little difficult to confirm the fix also :(